# Javascript countdown not displaying

Tags: javascript, html, setinterval

I'm trying to add a countdown to my page, but it is not displaying at all. 
Here's the HTML

```
<p id="countdown"></p>
```

And here's my javascript: (UPDATED)

```
var countDownDate = new Date("Sep 5, 2018 15:37:25").getTime();

// Update the count down every 1 second
var x = setInterval(function() {

    // Get todays date and time
    var now = new Date().getTime();

    // Find the distance between now an the count down date
    var distance = countDownDate - now;

    // Time calculations for days, hours, minutes and seconds
    var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
    var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
    var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
    var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

    // Display the result in the element with id="demo"
    document.getElementById("countdown").innerHTML = days + "d " + hours + "h "
+ minutes + "m " + seconds + "s ";

    // If the count down is finished, write some text 
    if (distance < 0) {
        clearInterval(x);
    }
},  1000);
```

Comment: You didn't set the time for the interval

Comment: So was it just a typo in your answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval), like [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout) requires 2 arguments: the callback function and the delay in milliseconds.

```
setInterval(function() {
    alert('2 seconds have elapsed!');
}, 2000);
```

You forgot to give the delay in milliseconds. With it your script runs fine.

```js
var countDownDate = new Date("Sep 5, 2018 15:37:25").getTime();

// Update the count down every 1 second
var x = setInterval(function() {

  // Get todays date and time
  var now = new Date().getTime();

  // Find the distance between now an the count down date
  var distance = countDownDate - now;

  // Time calculations for days, hours, minutes and seconds
  var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
  var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
  var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
  var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

  // Display the result in the element with id="demo"
  document.getElementById("countdown").innerHTML = days + "d " + hours + "h " +
    minutes + "m " + seconds + "s ";

  // If the count down is finished, write some text 
  if (distance < 0) {
    clearInterval(x);
    document.getElementById("countdown").innerHTML = "EXPIRED";
  }
}, 1000);
```

```html
<p id="countdown"></p>
```

Comment: I added an interval above - but I'm getting an error message about innerHTML cannot be null

Comment: index.js:21 

Which is: document.getElementById("countdown").innerHTML = days + "d " + hours + "h "

Comment: Try wrapping your code in an `window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', ...`  I updated the code snippet in my answer.

Comment: I'm not seeing your updates- working on adding it.  Weirdly enough when I run that code here it works, but when I run locally, its giving me that innerHTML cannot be null error.

Comment: @Desiree.tien It is working on my screen, try clearing your cache.

Comment: OH MY GOODNESS! @.@ I can't believe I didn't- Ugh either way thank you!

Comment: @Desiree If you use Google Chrome for development there is a setting in the Developer Tools that disables the cache while it is open. Has saved me many times.